# Axios get request from url

Tags: javascript, npm

So I'm having an issue with the npm package axios when trying to make a get request to a URL. I get an error code 503 every time; this is my code:

```
let data, response;

response = await axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
    }
})
```

So at first, I thought I did something wrong with the code (like changing Accept to 'Accept'), but when I do the exact same thing on Postman, it returns just fine.

Comment: did you miss some request headers like `Authorization`, if it works in Postman?

Comment: Look at [the meaning of the error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). We have no way of knowing why the server is outputting that. Debug the server.

Comment: @DengSihan I can recheck that.

Comment: @Quentin i searched the meaning of the error and axios put out "This service isn't currently avaible". But if that is the case, then why does it work with postman? if it is a problem with the server, shouldn't postman then also give the error?

Comment: @JordanBaveghems — "We have no way of knowing why the server is outputting that. Debug the server"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried by changing the `User-Agent` option in the headers to the one from Postman, and now it just seems to be working.

```
let data, response;

response = await axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.4',
    }
});
```

I'm still a bit new to http requests, so I really don't understand how this happens. I'm using [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) in other cases with different URL's too and there everything just runs fine.